# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for Rails model on new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Student and a controller Students. In the controller I have a new method

```rb
def new
  @student = Student.new
end
```

I then have a /views/students/new.html.haml that freaks out by using the @student. I get the error

```
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the haml for it

```
%h1 Students#new
%p Find me in app/views/students/new.html.haml

= form_for(@student) do |f|
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.button "Submit"
```

If I replace @student with Student.new I get the same results.

However if I start the server new and just use

```
= Student.new
```

I will get this output

```
#<Student:0x007fdf7a9c0778>
```

If I go into the rails console I can mess around with Students and use Student.new and Student.all and etc.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on or what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the error log from when I load localhost:3000/students/new

```
Started GET "/students/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 20:53:50 -0600
Processing by StudentsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `read_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:59:in `__temp__36c6163737'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/core.rb:171:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
app/controllers/students_controller.rb:3:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__289605414020287583__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3101080685994121215__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/daltondick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/daltondick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
```

/Users/daltondick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

```
Started POST "/__better_errors/70107129930940/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 20:53:51 -0600
```

Student model

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I just generated this model not too long ago with `rails g model Student` and then the controller with `rails g controller Students`

My migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string          :email
      t.string          :first_name
      t.string          :last_name
      t.string          :major
      t.string          :semester
      t.string          :class
      t.integer         :availability
      t.integer         :status

      t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

Running `Student.new.email = "foo"` gives me

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from /Users/daltondick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:86
Maybe IRB bug!
```

Comment: call `@student` from the view

Comment: Please show your new.html.haml

Comment: Wouldn't this pass your block to `Student.new` instead of `form_for`? Should probably wrap that method call in parens.

Comment: I wrapped the Student.new in parentheses and got the same result.

Comment: That's your complete new.html.haml?

Comment: Provide your error log please.

Comment: Is it safe to assume your Student model has an `email` attribute and you've run your migration?

Comment: Can you specify full stack trace for undefined method nil?

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra Yep, this is a new app just need to get stuff working to begin with and my model isn't working.

Comment: @AhmadHussain Does that log work for you?

Comment: What happens if you try `Student.new.email = 'foo'` in the rails console? This really looks like rails is not aware of the `email` attribute, which usually means that it was missing from your migration or the migration wasn't run.

Comment: How about `form_for [:student, @student]`?

Comment: The issue is in your model check this:app/controllers/students_controller.rb:3:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.2)

Comment: Problem occurs when you do Student.new can you send your model code may be there is some issue in model while initialization

Comment: @SteveRowley `Student.new.email = foo` gives me SystemStackError: stack level too deep
 from /Users/daltondick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:86
Maybe IRB bug!

Comment: If you didn't already, migrate the database - `rake db:migrate`. If you still get the same error in the console, I am stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're breaking things with `t.string :class`

`@student.class` *needs* to return `Student` for ActiveRecord to do its magic.

Your `@student.class` is going to return `nil`. That's a problem.

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland Don't change the behavior of `.class`. I thought that was very obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Why have you added a `class` attribute to `Student`? `class` is a Ruby keyword: `someobject.class` returns the class of `someobject`. You have added an attribute with same name, destroying this logic. Change the name of the attribute `class` to something else.

Comment: Because I was stupid. I'm moving over this website and that was the model before and it didn't even occur to me that it would interfere with Rubys .class Fixed it now thanks for the help.

Comment: `class` is a *Ruby* keyword, not a *Rails* keyword.

Comment: Sorry for mistake i wrote it in hurry